# CSS bottom-border property works when defined for element name but not class name

Tags: css, html-lists, border, nav, border-layout

For some odd reason, bottom-border works when I set the property to the "li" element, not for the defined "class" name (li-navclass). This presents a problem because I don't want the bottom border to be applied to the footer-links.

What I've tried:
-expanding the menu height
-bottom border, top-border
-different ways to write the property

Would greatly appreciate help on this. Thanks in advance!

```css
.container {
 position: absolute;
 background:url('../images/bgpic.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
 position: relative;
 margin: auto;
 padding: auto;
 height: 655px;
 width: 900px;
}

.titlehdr {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px; 
 display: inline-block;
 width: 897px;
 height: 110px;
}

.title-div {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 height: 100%;
 width: 90px;

 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}


.title {
 position: relative;
 top: 40px;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;

 font-size: 70px;
 color: white;
 font-family: Mesquite Std;
 letter-spacing: 1.2px;

}

.barandgrill-div {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: bottom;

}

.barandgrill-text {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 font-family: Arial;
 font-weight: bold;

}

/*---------------Nav Menu----------------*/
.menu {
 padding-left: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 font-size: 15px;
}

.nav-container {
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
 top: 100px;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 width: 900px;
 height: 40px;
 background-color: #901423;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
 border-color: #111111;
}

.menu {
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 margin: auto;
 padding: auto;
  list-style-type: none;
   overflow: hidden;
    font-color: #000000;
}

.li-navclass {
   border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}


li {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 padding: 0 1em;
 font-size: 150%;
}


.nav-text {
    color: #ffffff;
   font-weight: bold;
   opacity: .3;
}


.nav-container ul a {
 text-decoration: none;
    word-spacing: 200px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
   font-size: 20px;
   font-family: Segoe Script;
}

/*---------------Content----------------*/

.content {
 display: block;
 width: 900px;
 height: 500px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
 background-color: #111111;
 opacity: 0.6;
}

/*---------------Footer------------------*/

.foot {
 text-decoration: none;
 list-style-type: none;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 12px;
}

.ftr-button {
 position: relative;
 top: -5px;
 list-style: none;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: rgb(147, 104, 55);
}


.ftr-links {
 text-decoration: none;
 list-style-type: none;
}


.vert-line {
 height: 13px;
 border-right: 1px solid #909090;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <title>Sticky Navigation Tutorial</title>                  
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0"/>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen, projection" href="css/screen.css"/>

</head>

<body>
 <div class="container"> 
  
  <div class="wrapper"> 


  <!--Title-->
     <div class="titlehdr">
      <div class="title-div">
       <p class="title">Donatelo's</p>
      </div>

      <div class="barandgrill-div">
       <p class="barandgrill-text">Mediterranean Bar and Grill</p>
      </div>
     </div>

  <!--Navigation Menu-->
     <div class="nav-container">
      <ul class="menu">
       <li class="li-navclass"><a href="index.html" class="nav-text">Story</a></li>
       <li class="li-navclass"><a href="menu.html" class="nav-text">Menu</a></li>
       <li class="li-navclass"><a href="gallery.html" class="nav-text">Gallery</a></li>
       <li class="li-navclass"><a href="catering.html" class="nav-text">Catering</a></li>
       <li class="li-navclass"><a href="contact.html" class="nav-text">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>  
     </div>

  <!--Grey Box-->
     <div class="content">
      <div id="sidebar">
       <div id="scroller">
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>

  <!--footer-->
     <div class="foot">
      <ul class="ftr-links">
       <li class="vert-line"><a href="index.html" class="ftr-button">Story</a></li>
       <li class="vert-line"><a href="menu.html" class="ftr-button">Menu</a></li>
       <li class="vert-line"><a href="gallery.html" class="ftr-button">Gallery</a></li>
       <li class="vert-line"><a href="catering.html" class="ftr-button">Catering</a></li>
       <li class="vert-line"><a href="contact.html" class="ftr-button">Contact</a></li> 
      </ul>
      <p class="copyright">Copyright © 2015 Agabi Mediterranean Restaurant</p>  
     </div> 
  </div>


</body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".nav-text").mouseover(function() {
  $( this ).css( "opacity", ".8" );
});

$(".nav-text").mouseout(function() {
 $(this).css( "opacity", ".2");
});

$(".ftr-button").mouseover(function() {
 $(this).css("color", "rgb(132, 131, 129)");
});
$(".ftr-button").mouseout(function() {
 $(this).css("color", "rgb(147, 104, 55)");
});

$(".nav-text").click(function() {
 $(this).css("opacity", ".8");
});
});
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Your example works for me. What browser are you using?

Comment: That will most likely be because you have some other css assigned to the li element that overrides the li-navclass reference to it, in some other part of your css file or another file completely. This would explain why you seem to get erratic results when in fact its using order priority in the css stylesheet.

Comment: `border-bottom: 1px solid #000 !important;` Should fix it if you can't find the duplicate li reference.

Comment: It works on my PC... also Chrome here.

Comment: @pokeybit Unless the other one has !important too. Better to really fix it instead of abusing !important as a work-around.

Comment: I concur. I doubt it has though or it wouldn't work in his li either :)

Comment: Does the snippet work for you @Paul?

Comment: That's so weird. I'm using Version 43.0.2357.132 dev-m. Would that make a difference?

Comment: Tried that GolezTrol, still doesn't show on my screen.

Comment: Yeah, I see that it shows up on the Snippet. Might be the version of the browser then. Also tried on i.e version 9 and not showing.

Answer (score 0):

Add style to `:after`

```
.li-navclass:after {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```